# Empty rosinstall file for electric generated at packages.ros.org

Tags: ros, ros-electric, rosinstall, package, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone notice that the link provided for donwloading the ros base is empty?
I just check the link http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu/Source (ROS-Base -> Bare-Bones :  http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=ros-base&overlay=no) and its empty. Any update for it?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39718/empty-rosinstall-file-for-electric-generated-at-packages.ros.org/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-07-26**:
The authorities at Willow Garage are aware of this breakage and it will thus be fixed in due time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the outage, this has been fixed.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-07-29**:
Thanks. It's working now.

**Comment by [enodiesop](https://answers.ros.org/users/3856/enodiesop/) on 2013-01-08**:
I'm the same issue following Fuerte source installation, it would seem that the file is broken again ...?